# Why can't non-type template parameters be dependent on parameter of specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, metaprogramming, non-type-template-parameter

I've got this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename num_t, num_t num>
struct factorial {
    consteval operator num_t() { return num * factorial<num_t, num - 1>{}; }
};

template <typename num_t>
struct factorial<num_t, 2> {
    consteval operator char() { return 2; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << factorial<unsigned long long, 20>{} << '\n';
}
```

Clang gives me an error under `2` in `struct factorial<num_t, 2>`. The message is:

```
error: non-type template argument specializes a template parameter with dependent type 'num_t'
```

I've looked around a bit and it seems to be because of this part in the standard:

```
Paragraph [temp.class.spec] 14.5.5/8 of the standard:

The type of a template parameter corresponding to a specialized non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of the specialization. [ Example:

   template <class T, T t> struct C {};
   template <class T> struct C<T, 1>; // error

   template< int X, int (*array_ptr)[X] > class A {};
   int array[5];
   template< int X > class A<X,&array> { }; // error

—end example ]
```

Can someone explain the reasoning behind this section of the standard. It seems to me that they're simply getting in my way. What practical (or even theoretical) value comes with this rule?

Also, I'm more than a little confused about the wording that's being used. Can someone who understands maybe translate it into a more easy-to-understand phrasing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick way to fix it:

```
template <typename num_t, num_t num, typename = void>
struct factorial {
    constexpr operator num_t() { return num * factorial<num_t, num - 1>{}; }
};

template <typename num_t, num_t num>
struct factorial<num_t, num, std::enable_if_t<num == 2>> {
    constexpr operator char() { return 2; }
};
```

The reason is (likely), you can't construct `num_t num` without being aware of what `num_t` is; thus, compiler cannot match the `2`.

The paragraph basically says, template arguments are matched orthogonally, i.e., without co-dependency - this likely makes matching quicker in the compiler.

Comment: I'm aware of how to fix it, thanks anyway though. I also realized an error in my code that wasn't supposed to be there, which I've fixed. Now, the specialization should know what num_t is since I explicitly declare it to be unsigned long long. Deduction-wise, this should work, if only that rule didn't exist.

Comment: @NikTedig I can only guess. Likely compiler writers wanted match functions on template arguments to be orthogonal; otherwise, it's dificult to tell the exact order how the arguments should be deduced and that'd potentially make an O(N) check to an O(N^2) check. Per template match.

Comment: I guess that could be the reason. I doubt that though, since first of all, it can definitely be written better than O(n^2). You only need to match with types of arguments that have already passed (i.e. to the left of the current argument), just like normal template deduction works (as far as I know), which wouldn't be O(n^2). Second, you could probably use some cool hash map thing to speed everything up. Third, it's compilation speed, which is allowed to be a little bit slow (in my book at least). Fourth, when do you have templates with enough parameters to really slow things down?

Comment: @NikTedig I'm not sure that's how it works. When you write `2` to the `num_t` argument, that could be anything from `char` to `long long`; but it could be any of your custom types as well. So it has to match `num_t` first.

Comment: @NikTedig Probably the compiler wants to parse the 2 into some internal representation saying "int 2" or "char 2" or "unsigned long 2" but it can't do that. The standards committee thought it was reasonable enough that compilers should be able to do this, so they made it part of the standard.

Comment: @lorro Maybe I said it wrong, srry. That's what I meant. The relevant info to deduce the type of 2 is to the left of it in the template args, meaning I don't have to check every arg for every arg (e.g. nested loop e.g. quadratic time). You could accomplish the task faster than O(n^2). That was my point.

Comment: @lorro But I do understand your point. I'll see if I can find anything else online.

Comment: @NikTedig Yes, I understand why you say so in that phase. However, before that, all the compiler sees is `something<something1, numeric-constant>`. At this point, it cannot parse the numeric-constant to a typed value before processing something1 _and_ deducing that something<...> is actually this particular template matching header (not sure it's easy to follow this way). Note: I'm not saying this could not be made a part or extension of the standard; technically, it's algorithmically deducible.

Comment: @lorro It just bothers me that this technology already exists for normal templates (the base templates). Presumably, it would be relatively trivial to implement for specializations as well no?